# Button that publishes scheduled post in Wordpress when clicked?

Tags: wordpress

I'm looking to create a button for a Wordpress site to display in the top corner of the page that says "Click here if this site hasn't been updated since your last visit." Clicking this would trigger the next scheduled post to automatically be published instantly. If there are no scheduled posts, the button will take the visitor to a random post from the archive.

I want to avoid one person being able to click this button over and over. I'm a complete newbie to programming so I'm just hoping someone can point me in the right direction. I don't even know what to learn in order to be able to make this, so any hints would be hugely helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Are your users logged in or are they just viewing the public facing site?

Answer (score 0):

Look into the Wordpress documentation.  http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference contains all the Wordpress php functions.  You are going to want to get a basic understanding of php.  I'm not sure on the scheduled post part, but to get a random post you need

```
query_posts('orderby=rand
```